# How to have sshfs disk without auto-mount?

Tags: mount, ssh, fstab, sshfs

When i have partitions on local disk they appear as not-mounted. i can mount them in any program (krusader, nautilus) and then i can access them in all programs.

I want to have the same for sshfs. I want it to be visible as an unmounted disk / folder / partition that will be mounted on demand in any program (but without any command line). how to achieve that? some fstab entry with no-automont?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`fstab` manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/fstab.5) lists a useful option:

> **noauto** do not mount when "mount -a" is given (e.g., at boot time)

Could you try that option?